# Mini Electromagnetic Train

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics

referring to image uploaded [here](https://ibb.co/PMq2SDb),

[image: train]

this train levitation works by repelling forces and it does not even require any logic electronics to levitate it. However, if I were to use an electromagnet which can help to levitate by repelling force, the electromagnet seems to be quite bad. **For example, if I have 2 electromagnets and both are set to repel each other, the repulsion force would not be so great at close distance because it will be attracted to the iron core of electromagnet and this turns to be attracted to each other and not even repelling which is a big problem.** Thus, my question is whether there is a solution that I can make that uses all attraction forces instead of repulsive forces to levitate a train and without any microcontroller.

Thank you!!

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the server in stackexchange and images cannot be loaded,  but the image you link to is not easy to understand, with just a label "train"

Comment: @annav, well, those green highlighted ones are repelling magnets and they help levitate train :)

Comment: You write "because it will be attracted to the iron core of electromagnet"  which is wrong! the iron core just magnifies the magnetic field of the coil.

Comment: @trula, i mean the other electromganet will be attracted to the other electromagnet's iron core. And, of course i know it magnifies the magnetic field duhhhh

Comment: they fixed the problem with images, and I entered it in the question for clarity.